# fs.writeFileSync giving ENOENT error on Windows

Tags: node.js, fs

I have a fairly simple call to write a file (creating the directory structure if needed).

```
writeFileSync(fileName, output, { flag: "w" });
```

On Mac OS X this works as expected... On Windows, however, I get an ENOENT error:

```
fs.js:549   
return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\mydir\myfile.json'
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1156:15)
at ...
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
```

I'm really at a loss here b/c the file path listed is correct and valid. Moreover, this works exactly the way I want it to on Mac OS X.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: On windows path separator are different. When you make your path use ('path') module that build in. Something like this var fileName = path.join("/logs", "yourfilename");

Comment: Thanks @MykolaBorysyuk -- That was it... I was guilty of the boneheaded mistake of building my paths manually with `myDumbArrayOfPathString.join('/')` ... Once I implemented `path.join(...)` all is well. Thank you for the quick help!

Answer (score 3):

I was stupidly using

```
mySimpleArrayOfStrings.join('/'); // not the way to build a path
```

Instead of the very useful

```
path.join(...); // This is much better! Use this...
```

By not using this path, I was not accounting for the differing path separators in Windows.

**Huge thanks to @MykolaBorysyuk!**